# What's up with males named Miyuki?

Tags: manga, names, anime, gender

Edit 1: It's like [A Boy Named Sue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Boy_Named_Sue) or something.

Edit 2: Should I split this question into 2 posts so I can accept both answers? Huhuhu. I think I'll just accept 1 and bounty the other. It's a punishment for myself for not splitting up the post.

---

I notice in [Kaguya-sama](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kaguya-sama:_Love_Is_War), the name of the male protagonist is '[Miyuki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miyuki)', namely [白銀 御行, Shirogane Miyuki.](https://kaguyasama-wa-kokurasetai.fandom.com/wiki/Miyuki_Shirogane)

Apparently, the names of some of the characters in the anime/manga come from [The Tale of the Bamboo Cutter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Tale_of_the_Bamboo_Cutter) where there's a male character there named 'Miyuki', namely  Ōtomo no Miyuki (大納言大伴御行).

So we can see the kanji 御行 in both the Miyuki from Kaguya-sama and the Miyuki from The Tale of the Bamboo Cutter. Consistent, but...

1. ...what's up with that? How can males be named Miyuki?
2. Actually, when I plug the kanji into [nihongodera](https://nihongodera.com/tools/kana-converter) or google translate, what I get is, resp,  Ōtomo onkō and Ō tomo on kō. There doesn't seem to be any 'miyuki' here. What's going on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

みゆき as a masculine name is rare but not totally unheard of.

Here's an example: [戸部{とべ}実之{みゆき}](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E6%88%B8%E9%83%A8%E5%AE%9F%E4%B9%8B)

You are not alone in thinking みゆき sounds very feminine. Apparently it sounds feminine to a lot of native Japanese ears too. [The answerers here](https://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q1068572045) seem to unanimously consider みゆき a girl's name.

Comment: Wait what is that forum? Yahoo answers is still alive in yahoo japan? Or what? Edit: Omg I looked up yahoo answers on wikipedia just now 'The site ceased operations in most languages on May 4, 2021; though the Japanese version remains online.' So yeah that's what that is: Japanese yahoo answers?!

Comment: Btw I posted an answer. What do you think please?

Comment: @BCLC I am not sure I understand your answer...

Comment: [A Boy Named Sue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Boy_Named_Sue). Eddie Kal, at the time I made my question (march 2022), Miyuki's name's femininity wasn't addressed in the manga. Later in May 2022 it was finally addressed! So it is indeed a feminine name, and it's weird that it wasn't quite addressed hitherto in the manga!

Answer (score 3):

Partial answer, addressing #2 in the question post.  :)

[NihongoDera](https://nihongodera.com/tools/kana-converter) is not the best resource for names, which tend to have dedicated kanji readings that don't always match the usual on or kun.

You might have better luck with the ENAMDICT dictionary (the name-focused side of WWWJDIC), such as this mirror at Monash University:

- [http://nihongo.monash.edu/cgi-bin/wwwjdic?2MUJ御行](http://nihongo.monash.edu/cgi-bin/wwwjdic?2MUJ%E5%BE%A1%E8%A1%8C)

Change the string at the end of the URL to look up a different name, by kanji, kana, or romaji. Change the number `2` just after the `?` question mark to `1` to look up regular words. Or just use the website UI. :)

Name entries tend to have codes added in parentheses to the left of each romaji reading.  The entry above, with that code highlighted, looks like:

[image: Screenshot of ENAMDICT entry for given name 御行 "Miyuki"]

The `(u)` here is the code.  The [**Dictionary Codes**](http://nihongo.monash.edu/wwwjdicinf.html#code_tag) section of the help page, more specifically the **Names Dictionary Codes** sub-section (scroll down a bit -- it's not possible to link to that directly, unfortunately), explains what these mean.  According to the table there, the `u` code stands for "(as-yet) **u**nclassified" -- as compared to `s` for **s**urnames, or `g` for a **g**iven name that isn't yet classed by gender, or `f` for **f**emale given names, or `m` for **m**ale given names, etc.

Happy researching!

Comment: Btw I posted an answer. What do you think please?

Answer (score 0):

Oh wait a new chapter of Kaguya-sama [Chapter 264](https://kaguyasama-wa-kokurasetai.fandom.com/wiki/Chapter_264) was released on May 26, 2022 (last month and about 2 months after my post).

> I knew something was up!

> [image]

> [image]